# Spring MVC upload and stream to FTP

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ftp

I'm experiencing a problem where I need to transfer files to FTP using Spring MVC. The scenario is that user uploads a file to Spring Boot Server then a server is transferring the file to FTP.

**The problem** is that files can be huge. Is there a way (other than storing a file on disk - I want to avoid that) to stream the file to FTP as it's gets uploaded to Spring server? So that Spring server works like some kind of proxy to FTP.

Using the conventional way, I assume that Spring must receive the whole file, and only then it can transfer it to the FTP. During the process, the whole file must be kept in memory.  Am I right?

How can I avoid keeping the file in memory?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question might be of interest to you.  Although I haven't tried it myself.  But the gist of it is, you open a `URL` connection to an FTP endpoint and write to it's `OutputStream`.

[FtpOutputStream or similar in standard Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835716/ftpoutputstream-or-similar-in-standard-java)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I got the 'upload to ftp' covered. The part I don't get is 'receive upload to Spring and transfer it directly to outputstream without storing the file on memory'.

Comment: I'm not sure if Spring yet provides an out of the box way to "stream" a file upload to a remote server over FTP.  Looking through the docs though, you could make use of the CommonsMultipartResolver.  If you were able to map an NFS directory to the remote server and not use FTP, then you could use that NFS mapping as the temporary directory where uploaded files are stored, using CommonsMultipartResolver.